# How to stack two models to create a new model in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am preparing two models (one is a subset of another).

```
input_shape = (480, 800, 3)
conv_layer = Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=5, strides=(1, 1), padding="same")

# The outputs of the conv layer match the inputs of model_1
model_1 = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV3Small(input_shape)
model_2 = conv_layer + model_1  # I need help with this line
```

I would like to create the `model_2` such that it has an additional Conv2D layer. The parameters of the `conv_layer` ensure that the input size is the same as its output. Therefore, it should be possible to stack `conv_layer` and `model_1` to generate `model_2`.

I was thinking of creating a model with only the `conv_layer`, like:

```
conv_model = Sequential([
               Input(shape=input_shape),
               Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=5, strides=(1, 1), padding="same")
             ])
```

In this case, I will have to stack two models `conv_model` and `model_1` to create `model_2`.

I am not sure how to do either of the two, to achieve what I need.

Edit: Fixed the padding in `conv_layer` to ensure the input size are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add `model_1` to `Sequential`. Also please note that the outputs of the conv layer **don't** match the inputs of model_1 - you need to use `padding="same"` for that:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_shape = (480, 800, 3)
conv_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=5, strides=(1, 1), padding="same")
model_1 = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV3Small(input_shape)
model_2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape),
    conv_layer,
    model_1
])
# let's test that everything works on random data
model_2.predict(np.random.random((1, 480, 800, 3)))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with padding. I will edit this in the question.